# Влияние head на seo

Tags: html, seo

В wordpress, например, используется один head на все страницы, следовательно и заголовок, и описание, и ключевые слова одинаковые на всех страницах. Как это влияет на индексацию сайта поисковиками?

Comment: Так он там динамический же

Comment: *В вордпрессе, например, используется один head на все страницы* - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Заголовки и описания страниц должны быть уникальны, то есть они должны описывать содержание конкретной страницы. Правильное применения этих элементов помогает поисковикам понять содержание страницы и отобразить её в поисковой выдаче. Подробнее смотрите [справка Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=ru).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress - это система управления контентом. Ключевое слово - СИСТЕМА.
В этой системе много php файлов, которые взаимодействуют с базой данных. head может быть и один, но в нужные места этого хеда подставляется различная информация, когда сервер генерирует страницу перед показом ее пользователю.
Например в тег title каждой страницы подставляются определенные значения из базы данных.
не хочу лезть в код, но на примере вот что там приблизительно:

```
<title>{$meta_title|escape}{$filter_meta->title|escape}</title>
```

Это значит, что для поисковых систем сайт виден таким образом, как его видят пользователи, а значит все в порядке.

Часто даже подключаются переменные для перевода языков в тайтл. Можете взять себе эту информацию на вооружение и попытаться реализовать. Я просто не помню, в Wordpress это реализовано как базовая функция или в качестве дополнения.

Поисковики уж точно не будут понижать ваш сайт в выдаче, если на каждую страницу будут реализованы переводы тайтлов и других текстовых данных, видимые пользователю и ПС.